# How do I filter NSMetadataQuery

Tags: nspredicate, nsmetadataquery, icloud-drive

I am trying to create a `NSMetadataQuery` with a predicate. At a certain point I may want to gather all videos iCloud may have at another point all images. I don't want anything else, just search for videos or search for images. Not both at the same time.

I have created this code:

```
CFStringRef whatToFilter = kUTTypeImage;
if (self.filterType == kKindVideo) {
    whatToFilter = kUTTypeVideo;
}

NSPredicate *predType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", NSMetadataItemContentTypeKey, whatToFilter];

NSMetadataQuery *newQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[newQuery setSearchScopes:@[NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
newQuery.predicate = predType;
```

as soon as I add this predicate to `newQuery` it gives me zero results.

What is the correct syntax for this query? Don't tell me that the predicate is also not working for `NSMetadataQuery`, because sort is not working either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to create a correct `NSMetadataQuery` predicate is to use the Finder's query expression editor, like so:

[image: Smart Folder query expression editor]

Then save it as a Smart Folder and **Get Info** on the resulting folder:

[image: Smart Folder info]

The relevant Spotlight query syntax is, in this instance: `"(kMDItemUserTags == 'Assets'cd)"`... (Ignore the `_kMDItemGroupId` subexpression, as attribute names beginning with underscores are not public API.)

Finally, let `NSPredicate` figure out how it wants the query string rewritten:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(fromMetadataQueryString: "(kMDItemUserTags == 'Assets'cd)")
```

Comment: `NSPredicate(fromMetadataQueryString:` is a great find.